STM32: read data in device sent by host over USB HID
In an STM32CubeIDE USB HID project for an STM32F103C8 board I can send data from the device to the host using the USBD_HID_SendReport() function, like so:
USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, (uint8_t*)&hid_report,sizeof(hid_report));

How can I read data in the device sent over USB HID by the host?
In particular, I'd like to send arbitrary data (say, 1024 bytes) from the host using something like hid_write() from libusb's hidapi and then read it in the STM32 device.
How can I do that?

The full main.c looks something like:
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"
#include "usbd_hid.h"

extern USBD_HandleTypeDef hUsbDeviceFS;

static uint8_t hid_report[0x08] = {0x00};

int main(){
    HAL_Init();            // reset all peripherals, init the Flash interface and the Systick?
    SystemClock_Config();  // configure the system clock
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();

    while(1){
        hid_report[0x02] = 0x04;
        USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, (uint8_t*)&hid_report,sizeof(hid_report));
        HAL_Delay(50);

        hid_report[0x02] = 0x00;
        USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, (uint8_t*)&hid_report,sizeof(hid_report));
        HAL_Delay(1000);
    }
}

But now I need some kind of callback somewhere that triggers whenever the USB device (the STM32) receives data from the host (the PC).
As a bonus, I need to write that data to flash.

The ST library for HID demo device does not implement the dataout field. Maybe you can inspire from the CDC examples to fill the gaps (create a end-point for receiving data, registering callbacks, ...).

Thank you. I'm also thinking of creating a Custom HID device (using STM32CubeIDE), which I think does implement the data out. But then the question is how to get the USB host to recognize it as a keyboard.

I guess you can change the device descriptor to a keyboard and keep the surrounding logic for send/control (which is implemented in the CustomHID demo).
